# Adding a post to a page

Tags: posts, menus, pages

I would like to know how I can add a specific post to a specific page? It would be great if anyone can suggest a reference to this problem.

Do I need to create a post category to relate with a page? Or should I add a category on menu widgets rather than page?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want to add specific Post's content/title/other stuff to specific Page, You can just use [get_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) function. But Your formulation of question very vague.

Answer (score 0):

Page cannot have a post. These are two different "[post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)".

Why do you want to add a post to a page in the first place? You can give a post a category and it will show on a "category page" which is actually a listing of all posts with that category. You could then have a custom `category-slug.php` where `slug` is the slug of that category so the posts with that category would show with that template and you could do whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a separate page for each post then you can have a custom page template depending upon your page slug like `page-page_slug.php` and inside the page template you can specify the `query` using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Ex. `$query = new WP_Query( 'p=7' );`

here `7` is the id of the post. You can set it as per your requirement.

Refer [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) for more possible parameters.

And using the_loop you can display the single post on the single page.